# How to find mail on shared linux hosting and delete after forwarding

Tags: linux, email, shared-hosting, find

I'm forwarding mail from a shared hosting account to a gmail address.  The mail forwarder does not delete the mail after forwarding so the directory is getting full.

I tried the following in a cron job, but it only seems to delete one file at a time.  I want to run the cronjob once a month and delete all files, not just the first file found.

```
find /home/myshare/mail/foo/new -type f -mtime 0 -print0 | xargs rm -f
```

I also tried this variation of the `find` command, but it also only deletes one file:

```
find /home/myshare/mail/foo/new -delete
```

My access to the server is via CPanel.  How do I delete all files in a directory with a single command in a cronjob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `-print0` flag with find, you will want to use `xargs -0`.

Answer (score 0):

how about
find /home/myshare/mail/foo/new -type f -mtime 0 -exec rm -rf {} \;

or rm -rf /home/myshare/mail/foo/new/*